# HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden -When publishing MVC 4 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web-hosting

This seems like a question that has already been asked/answered many times. Its not.

Development Environment: VS 2013 and MVC 4, Visual C#. I am using the built in IIS Express to run the app.

When publishing the site using Ftp details , it shows published succesfully and , all the files are stored inside the wwwroot folder(checked using FileZilla)

But when i open the site , shows the following error

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
Most likely causes:

A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.

Things you can try:

If you do not want to enable directory browsing, ensure that a default document is configured and that the file exists.
Enable directory browsing using IIS Manager.
    Open IIS Manager.
    In the Features view, double-click Directory Browsing.
    On the Directory Browsing page, in the Actions pane, click Enable.
Verify that the configuration/system.webServer/directoryBrowse@enabled attribute is set to true in the site or application configuration file.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     DirectoryListingModule
Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code     0x00000000
Requested URL      http://www.infokairali.com:80/
Physical Path      E:\HostingSpaces\infokairali\infokairali.com\wwwroot
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous
```

I already done all the things in IIS , above mentioned. 
and change the web.config file like

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers></system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

but the same error still remains. Please help me

Comment: the identity set in the application pool has rights on E:\HostingSpaces\infokairali\infokairali.com\wwwroot ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's a routing issue. By default there's a default controller and action in the route such as:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I tried commenting out "defaults" parameter above and started to get HTTP 403.14 error. Please make sure the defaults are set to a valid controller and action.